# How to make multiple list expansions for a single type using natvis Visual Studio C++ debugger visualizer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, natvis

I'm trying to make debugger visualizer for container that stores values in chunks. I want to make list expansion both for values and for chunks, but as far as I can see single type can have only one list expansion. There may be multiple `Expand` subnodes like `ArrayItems` but they all produce single list.
Yes, I can make chunks expansion for container and then make value expansion for each chunk. But  I want two container subnodes with expandsions like this:

```
MyList
|-values
| |-0
| |-1
|
|-chunks
| |-0
| |-1
```

Is there a way to do it using natvis xml?

Comment: I suggset that you could use `Synthetic item expansion`.It allows you to create an artificial child element that isn't a result of an expression. The artificial element can have child elements of its own.  You could refer to [Micorsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<Synthetic>` for that. The code inside `<Synthetic>` can be for example `<Item>` or `<ArrayItems>`, but also any other item type.

```xml
<Type Name="MyList">
  <DisplayString>...</DisplayString>
  <Expand>
    <Synthetic Name="values">
      <DisplayString>...</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
        <!-- code for displaying as values -->
      </Expand>
    </Synthetic>
    <Synthetic Name="chunks">
      <DisplayString>...</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
        <!-- code for displaying as chunks-->
      </Expand>
    </Synthetic>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```